# Android deelay between methods call

Tags: java, android

I have an aplication that gets the count of the user_id on the database to check if the user exists or not.

the code I am having problem:

```
registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        usernameR = usernameRgt.getText().toString();
        emailR = emailRgt.getText().toString();
        passwordR = passwordRgt.getText().toString();
        repeatR = repeatPassRgt.getText().toString();
        new userExistsTask().execute(new ApiConnector());
        if ((usernameR == null || usernameR.isEmpty() == true) || (emailR == null || emailR.isEmpty() == true) || (passwordR == null || passwordR.isEmpty() == true) || (repeatR == null || repeatR.isEmpty() == true)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "One or more fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (userExistN == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Não existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It works the way I want to the problem is that the call to the `new userExistsTask().execute(new ApiConnector());`(method that set the variable `userExistsN` value) takes some time to execute and the if gets the wrong value to the variable `userExistsN` so **there is a way to put a delay between the if and the method call?**

Update:

userExistYask() code:

```
private class userExistsTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

        // it is executed on Background thread

        return params[0].userExists(usernameR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        if (jsonArray != null) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                userExistN = json.getInt("userCount");
                System.out.println(userExistN);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for userExistsTask.  Is it an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you put the IF code in  separate method and call this method from postExecute? This guarantees the method won't be called till the background method is done

Comment: This would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: so I just put this code between the if and the call?

Comment: The code inside the run method is executed after 5000 ms.  In your case I think you want to put all your "if-s" inside the run() { ...} method

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple issues here.  You're calling your AsyncTask even if the text fields are empty, which is not needed.

To solve your main issue, just move the functionality that requires the result of the AsyncTask to onPostExecute().

Something like this:

```
    registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        usernameR = usernameRgt.getText().toString();
        emailR = emailRgt.getText().toString();
        passwordR = passwordRgt.getText().toString();
        repeatR = repeatPassRgt.getText().toString();
        if ((usernameR == null || usernameR.isEmpty() == true) || (emailR == null || emailR.isEmpty() == true) || (passwordR == null || passwordR.isEmpty() == true) || (repeatR == null || repeatR.isEmpty() == true)) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "One or more fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
           new userExistsTask().execute(new ApiConnector());

        }
    }
});
```

Then your AsyncTask:

```
private class userExistsTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

        // it is executed on Background thread

        return params[0].userExists(usernameR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        if (jsonArray != null) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                userExistN = json.getInt("userCount");

                //change this to Lod.d(Tag, userExistN);
                System.out.println(userExistN);

                if (userExistN == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(int userExistN);
}
```

In userExistsTask class:

```
private class userExistsTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
        return params[0].userExists(usernameR);
    }
    :
    :
    :
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    delegate.processFinish(userExistN);
}
```

In Activity `onCreate()`

```
    userExistsTask existsTask = new userExistsTask();
    existsTask.execute(new ApiConnector());
    existsTask.delegate = this;

    void processFinish(int userExistN){
       if ((usernameR == null || usernameR.isEmpty() == true) || (emailR == null || emailR.isEmpty() == true) || (passwordR == null || passwordR.isEmpty() == true) || (repeatR == null || repeatR.isEmpty() == true)) {
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "One or more fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
           if (userExistN == 0) {
               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Não existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
    }
```